# How to put Values on Boxplot in R for several boxplot in one image

Tags: r, compare, boxplot

I want to plot Delta~Project.Types in R. I have 10 Project Types. I know how to do the boxplot :
boxplot(Delta~Project.Types). However, how can I put the fivenum (min, max, 1st, 2nd, and 3rd quantile) on each boxplot? How can I do for that every boxplot of the image will have its five number shown? That would be easier to compare the boxplots when the values are shown

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The stats you want can also be obtained with `fivenum`

```
five <- by(InsectSprays$count, InsectSprays$spray, fivenum)
do.call(cbind, five)
#         A    B   C    D   E  F
# [1,]  7.0  7.0 0.0  2.0 1.0  9
# [2,] 11.0 12.0 1.0  3.5 2.5 12
# [3,] 14.0 16.5 1.5  5.0 3.0 15
# [4,] 18.5 18.0 3.0  5.0 5.0 23
# [5,] 23.0 21.0 7.0 12.0 6.0 26
```

Alternatively, these stats are one of the return values of `boxplot` (note that you need to use `range = 0` to get the min and max since there are some values which are outlying):

```
bp <- boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray", range = 0)
bp$stats
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]  7.0  7.0  0.0  2.0  1.0    9
# [2,] 11.0 12.0  1.0  3.5  2.5   12
# [3,] 14.0 16.5  1.5  5.0  3.0   15
# [4,] 18.5 18.0  3.0  5.0  5.0   23
# [5,] 23.0 21.0  7.0 12.0  6.0   26
```

Then just add to each box:

```
text(x = col(bp$stats) - .5, y = bp$stats, labels = bp$stats)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a "legend" to a base R plot that contains what you want like this:

```
legend("topright", bty = "n", legend = summary(Delta))
```

I'm assuming that it's "Delta" that you're running summary() on, so change that as needed. You can modify the appearance of what shows up in the legend using paste(), i.e.

```
legend("topright", bty = "n", legend = c(paste("min =", summary(Delta)[1]),
                                     paste("max =", summary(Delta)[2])))
```

etc.